# How to connect rails development.sqlite3 database for the single ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I have a `main.rb` for Telegram bot. For creating Admin panel of the bot I have used the Rails. 
So now I want to connect from `main.rb` file to the database which I created using Rails.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this inside of main.rb...

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'sqlite3',
  database: 'DB_NAME',
  username: 'DB_USER',
  password: 'DB_PASS',
  host:     'localhost'
)

# This will connect to the bots tables, probably not what you wanted.
class Bot < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```